# Should i have exception prevent users entering e.g. {0} or {2} in strings

Tags: c#

Like today i found out that something like this can occur. I put the value directly in the string but lets say that the user put it. **Updated example**:

```
   int age = 21; // Users gives age 21
   string s1 = "John {0}"; // Users gives name john and inputs this too {0}

   Console.WriteLine(s1, age); // Me wanting to show his name along with the {0} and the age

Output is :John 21
Outpout wanted is John {0} 21
```

Comment: But that's what the very overload of `Console.WriteLine` is for?  What do you _want_ the output to be if the user puts a `{0}` in a string while you're calling that overload?

Comment: i Want it to show Hello {0}.

Comment: So why are you passing `number`?

Comment: Or simply prevent them from imputing that.

Comment: @James Thorpe i am passing number just to show what happens.= in this example with the string.

Comment: If you don't want it to automatically format the string with extra information, don't call the overload that formats strings with extra information.  `Console.WriteLine(s1)` will happily output `Hello {0}`

Comment: James but if i had something else that i  needed to call including the Hello {0}?

Comment: I think you need to improve your example with different inputs/expected outputs.  Right now it's really not clear what your question actually is.

Comment: Right, that's a bit clearer.  I think you probably need to go and look at the documentation for `Console.WriteLine`.  It's not like `console.log` in JavaScript, if that's where you're coming from, in that it won't log all arguments passed to it consecutively, rather by passing differing numbers of arguments, you get different behaviours.  This is called overloading - a function with one name can have vastly different behaviours depending on which overload you call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call this:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", "John {0}", 21);
```

(Here `"{0} {1}"` is a format you supply, not something the user entered.)

The output will be:

```
John {0} 21
```

By formatting the data the user entered the braces are not treated as special.

In your code you would call this as:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", s1, age);
```

Comment: Cant do that cause i cant know what value the string will have since the user actually inputs the values so i would have no way of knowing if he messed up and added the {0} along with his name.

Comment: @GeorgeOscStephan This answer means you don't have to care whether he put `{0}` in or not.

Comment: But how can i call `Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", "John {0}", 21);` When i dont know the name or his age or do you mean this is the same as `Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", s1, age);`

Comment: Yes, Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", s1, age);

Comment: Thanks chosen best answer.